# android-how to start a shared element transition from marker bitmap?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I'm using custom bitmaps as the icon of markers on the map. when the user clicks on any marker, I want to have a view corresponding to the clicked bitmap and add it as a shared element to the fragment transition. but I can't see any method to retrieve the bitmap from the marker. so how to start a shared element transition from the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: use `setTag()/getTag()` methods to save/restore bitmap in marker object and additional `ImageView` with this bitmap as shared element for transitions between "map" and "details" fragments:

[image: shared marker icon]

**TLDR;**

In case you "using custom bitmaps as the icon of markers" you can store them in [`Marker`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) objects with [`setTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method and then retrieve marker's icon bitmap in [`onMarkerClick(Marker marker)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener#onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)) method. But bitmap is not enough for [shared element transitions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#shared), because object of `View` class needed to perform it. So, you need to create additional `View` (e.g. `ImageView`) and use it as shared element for transitions between "map" and "details" fragments.

In general you should:

- **On application start** (*in `MainActivity`*):

1. create "map" fragment with `ImageView` for shared element transition perform;
2. create "details" fragment with corresponding`ImageView` for shared element transition perform;
3. create shared element transition animations;

- **When marker created** (*in "map" fragment*):

1. just save bitmap in marker object.

- **When user clicked on marker**,

*in "map" fragment*:

1. in retrieve saved bitmap from marker object;
2. set retrieved bitmap to shared `ImageView`;
3. resize `ImageView` and move it to set exactly over the marker icon;
4. hide marker icon and show `ImageView` with marker icon instead of marker;
5. put marker bitmap (and e.g. description) to "details" fragment via arguments;
6. create and start `FragmentTransaction`;

*in "details" fragment*:

1. get marker bitmap and description from arguments and show them on corresponding `ImageView` and `TextView`;

- **When user close "details" fragment**(*in "map" fragment*),

1. wait for transition animation end and show marker/hide `ImageView`.

Most challenged part of that is create shared view inside "map" fragment, because `SupportMapFragment` did not have such element "from the box". So you need to create custom `CustomSupportMapFragment` that extends `SupportMapFragment` and have additional `ImageView` for shared element transitions:

```
public class CustomSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private float mY;
    private float mX;

    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private ImageView mSharedImageView;

    private Marker mMarker;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(root.getContext());
        mRelativeLayout.addView(root, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));

        mSharedImageView = new ImageView(root.getContext());
        mSharedImageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        mSharedImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        mSharedImageView.setTransitionName("sharedImageView");

        mRelativeLayout.addView(mSharedImageView);

        return mRelativeLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mSharedImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            mSharedImageView.setX(mX);
            mSharedImageView.setY(mY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mSharedImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        mX = mSharedImageView.getX();
        mY = mSharedImageView.getY();
    }

    public void setSharedMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }


    public void setSharedViewInitialPosition(float x, float y) {
        mSharedImageView.setX(x);
        mSharedImageView.setY(y);
    }

    public void setSharedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mSharedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public ImageView getSharedView() {
        return mSharedImageView;
    }

    public void showMarker() {
        if (mMarker != null) mMarker.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

"Details" fragment can be typical like that:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.picture_iv);
        mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.details_tv);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("image");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            String description = getArguments().getString("description");
            mTextView.setText(description);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

with layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture_iv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:transitionName="sharedImageView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_tv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:text="Description"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NB!** Same `"sharedImageView"` name of transition needed across all "map" and "details" fragments views.

And `MainActivity` should implement marker click processing logic:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final LatLng KYIV = new LatLng(50.450311, 30.523730);
    static final LatLng DNIPRO = new LatLng(48.466111, 35.025278);

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private CustomSupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private DetailsFragment detailsFragment;

    public class DetailsEnterTransition extends TransitionSet {
        public DetailsEnterTransition() {
            setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
            addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).
                    addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).
                    addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
        }
    }

    public class DetailsExitTransition extends TransitionSet {
        public DetailsExitTransition(final CustomSupportMapFragment mapFragment) {
            setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
            addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).
                    addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).
                    addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
            addListener(new TransitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                    if (mapFragment != null) {
                        mapFragment.showMarker();
                        mapFragment.setSharedBitmap(null);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create "map" fragment
        mapFragment = new CustomSupportMapFragment();

        // create "details" fragment and transitions animations
        detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
        detailsFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsEnterTransition());
        detailsFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsExitTransition(mapFragment));

        // show "map" fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, mapFragment, "map")
                .commit();

        // get GoogleMap object
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_kyiv);
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 250, false);

                Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(KYIV)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap))
                        .title("Kyiv"));
                marker.setTag(resizedBitmap);  // save bitmap1 as tag of marker object
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(KYIV));

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_dnipro);
                resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 250, false);
                marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(DNIPRO)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap))
                        .title("Dnipro"));
                marker.setTag(resizedBitmap); // save bitmap2 as tag of marker object

                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(KYIV));

                mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        // retrieve bitmap for marker
                        Bitmap sharedBitmap = (Bitmap)marker.getTag();

                        // determine position of marker and shared element on screen
                        Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
                        Point viewPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
                        final float x = viewPosition.x - sharedBitmap.getWidth() / 2.0f;
                        final float y = viewPosition.y - sharedBitmap.getHeight();

                        // show shared ImageView and hide marker
                        mapFragment.setSharedMarker(marker);
                        mapFragment.setSharedBitmap(sharedBitmap);
                        mapFragment.setSharedViewInitialPosition(x, y);
                        mapFragment.getSharedView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mapFragment.getSharedView().invalidate();
                        marker.setVisible(false);

                        // prepare data for "details" fragment
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable("image", sharedBitmap);
                        bundle.putString("description", marker.getTitle());
                        detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        // create and start shared element transition animation
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.addSharedElement(mapFragment.getSharedView(), mapFragment.getSharedView().getTransitionName());
                        ft.replace(R.id.container, detailsFragment, "details");
                        ft.addToBackStack("details");
                        ft.commit();

                        return true; // prevent centring map on marker
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And that's it. Note: this is not fully-functional commercial code, just illustration.